# Using flash message after submitting form in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am just trying to show a bootstrap style alert after submitting a contact form with Node JS/Express. I am using an ejs template for my view

**mailerRoutes.js**

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const mailer = require('express').Router();

<!-- more mailer config here --->

function sendEmail(req, res) {
 transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
  if(error){
    req.flash('msg', 'error occurred');
    res.locals.messages = req.flash();
  }else{
    req.flash('msg', 'Successfully sent email');
    res.locals.messages = req.flash();
  };
  res.redirect('/');
 });
}

module.exports = mailer;
```

**server.js**

```
const mailerRoutes = require('./routes/mailerRoutes');

app.use(cookieParser('secret'));
app.use(session({ 
  cookie: { maxAge: 60000 },
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET || '<mysecret>',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false 
}));
app.use(flash());

app.use('/changeInfo', mailerRoutes);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  RugbyClub.count({}, (err, count) => {
  if (err) {
    res.render('index', { count: [] });
    return;
  }
    res.render('index', { count: count });
 });
});
```

**index.ejs**

```
<% if (locals.messages) { %>

<script language="javascript">
  alert("<%= messages.msg %>");
</script>

<% } %>
```

I'm clearly doing something wrong as nothing happens but I would like to redirect and then show the message, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your flash messages available to the request local object, the request object property is useful for exposing request-level information.

```
req.flash("msg","Error Occured");
res.locals.messages = req.flash();
res.redirect('/');
```

You then put this in your views file with the rest of your application logic:

```
<% if (locals.messages) { %>
<% } %>
```

And in mailRouter.js maybe try doing this instead:

```
exports.sendEmail = function(req, res) {
// I hope you had imported the Nodemailer module
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    // Put everything else here
```

Finally you change the following line in your server.js:

```
app.use('/changeInfo', mailerRoutes);
// To
app.use('/changeInfo', mailerRoutes.sendEmail);
```

I assumed that there may be more functions you may add to the mailerRoutes.js file, hence the decision to use exports. Hope this helps.

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer, i have updated my question with my current config but the alert never pops up, any ideas at all please ?

Comment: @Richlewis It should atleast pop up, did you tick the "prevent this page from creating additional dialog" earlier?